# Как подключится к бд через DataSource (у меня получается подключится только к бд test)?

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee

Здравствуйте. 
Настроил подключение к бд через DataSource. 
[image: DataSource]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но какую бы базу я не указал все время подключаюсь к базе тест:
[image: вывод программы]

```
@WebServlet("/Main")
public class Main extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Context ctx;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

@Resource(name = "MySqlDS")
private DataSource dataSource;

public Main() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()){
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs =st.executeQuery("SELECT DATABASE()");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String count = rs.getString("DATABASE()");
            out.println("Database: " + count);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    doGet(request, response);
}
```

}

Если использовать драйверМенеджер, то все работает.
Подскажите что нужно сделать что-бы подключится к другой бд.

Comment: Имя ресурса правильное указать в @Resource

Comment: Имя ресурса правильное указать в @Resource. На странице конфигурации подключения перейдите в Attributes, найдите и запомните атрибут JNDI. Запомнили? Теперь напишите то что запомнили в ... @Resource(name="сюда")

Comment: Sergey, на странице Attributes, в строке JNDI у меня написано: java:/MySqlDS. Если я это подставлю в аннотацию ( @Resource(name = "java:/MySqlDS")), то получу множество исключений. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Ошибки можно посмотреть здесь - http://dim.st/t0a2e.txt

Comment: К самому серверу mysql я подключаюсь и могу с ним работать. Вот только ограничен только базой, которая создана по умолчанию - test. Хотя в url указана база - Frewor

Comment: А так @Resource(lookup="java:/MySqlDS")? lookup точно должен искать заданный JNDI. А name какой-то мутный атрибут.

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Resource` используется для инъекции ресурсов и для маппинга ресурсов.
Только нет единого мнения нужно ли делать и то и другое или только что-то одно в зависимости от обстоятельств применения этой аннотации.

Похоже wildfly делает и то и другое. Т.е. связывает указанный name с указанным lookup и потом внедряет в поле то, что получилось в результате lookup-а.

Если не указывать name или lookup, то для этих параметров используются значения по-умолчанию.

`@Resource(name = "MySqlDS")` =
`@Resource(name = "MySqlDS", lookup="java:comp/DefaultDataSource")`
Имя `MySqlDS` отображается в `java:comp/DefaultDataSource` и в поле внедряется `java:comp/DefaultDataSource`. Если не ошибаюсь в wildfly это ExampleDS. Вы не меняли ExampleDS в настройке сервера, чтобы он подключался к Вашей базе test? Или меняли параметр default datasource?

Пробуем написать `@Resource(name = "java:/MySqlDS")`.
Получится `@Resource(name = "java:/MySqlDS", lookup="java:comp/DefaultDataSource")`
Но `java:/MySqlDS` уже задействовано в конфигурации сервера, и указывает на что-то отличное от `java:comp/DefaultDataSource`. Отсюда и исключения.

Теперь напишем `@Resource(lookup = "java:/MySqlDS")`. name по умолчанию как-то вычисляется по имени поля. Но нам этот name не так уж и нужен, главное что теперь-то точно будет внедряться нужная база.